# Using javascript object to call function and virables

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Am trying to advance my javascript code, by using it as an object so i can call it when needed but it doesn't work. Please can someone help me out i will appreciate it.

```
var AppObject = {
    var targetElement = "#AjaxLoadBodyContentLoader";       
    init: function (hashUrl, defaultBack){
        if(hashUrl != defaultBack && hashUrl != ""){
            var LoadHashUrl = hashUrl+' #AjaxLoadBodyContentLoader';
            $('#AjaxLoadBodyContentLoader').load(
                LoadHashUrl,
                {"async_content" : "true", "PrevLink" : defaultBack}
            );
        }
    },
    asyncShowContent: function(){
        /*$.getScript("external.js");*/
        $(this.targetElement).show('normal', this.asyncPregressBar);
    },
    asyncPregressBar: function(){
        $('#preloader').fadeOut();
        $('#status').fadeOut();
    },
    asyncLoader: function(){
        $(this.targetElement).load(
            this.linkPath,
            {"async_content" : "true", "PrevLink" : this.PrevLink},
            function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
                this.asyncShowContent();
                console.log("Status: " + xhr.status + " | Text: " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        );
    },
    asyncExtecute: function(e){
        var targetUrl = e.target.href;  
        if(typeof targetUrl == 'undefined' || targetUrl == ""){
           targetUrl = $(this).attr('href');
        }
        var linkPath = targetUrl + ' ' + this.targetElement;
        var PrevLink = $(this).attr('data-page-link');

        window.location.hash = targetUrl;

        $('#preloader').fadeIn(); 
        $('#status').fadeIn();
        $(this.targetElement).hide('fast',this.asyncLoader);
    }
}
```

Using the above code without adding it inside `AppObject={}`, work very fine, but i want to advance it and learn more how to use javascript object.

Usage

```
$(function(){
    AppObject.init(
        window.location.hash.substr(1), 
        location.href.replace(location.hash,"")
    );                                      

    $(document).on('click', 'a.LoadPage', function(e){
        AppObject.asyncExtecute(e);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please show the exact error you are receiving?

Comment: You could use the es6 class syntax.

Comment: Specifically, what’s the problem?  “Doesn’t work” rules out one of, well, infinite possibilities.

Comment: Object cannot just be a block of code. Specifically in this case it's your first line that is the problem. It *might* work if you change it to: `targetElement: "#AjaxLoadBodyContentLoader",` However you might get issues with using `this`, I am not sure though as I don't code my JS like this, and I am not going to test it for you either

Comment: @EvanBechtol it does't show any error

Comment: @James yes it doesn't work, instead of loading the content as supposed it open the link location

Comment: you need to move out of object this thing - `var targetElement = "#AjaxLoadBodyContentLoader";`

Answer (score 1):

As @musefan says in a comment, you have a syntax problem:

This is wrong:

```
var AppObject = {
    var targetElement = "#AjaxLoadBodyContentLoader";
    ...       
}
```

This is a variable declaration:

```
var targetElement = "#AjaxLoadBodyContentLoader";
```

Inside an object, you need to use **key/value pairs**:

```
var AppObject = {
        targetElement : "#AjaxLoadBodyContentLoader",
    ...      
}
```

**EDIT**: e is undefined

`e` should be your event, you need it in asyncExtecute,

```
var AppObject = {
    asyncExtecute: function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // Add this line, to prevent the browser to immediately navigate to other window
        var targetUrl = e.target.href;  
        ...
    }
}

$(function(){
    ...
    $(document).on('click', 'a.LoadPage', function(e){
        AppObject.asyncExtecute(e); // Here you are passing the event object to asyncExtecute
    });
});
```

Comment: Now am getting TypeError: e is undefined using this method

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the way you are adding property to your object. Please add it as below:

```
var AppObject = {
    targetElement: "#AjaxLoadBodyContentLoader",
    //remaining code---
};
```